# how to change comment_box userImage on flutter with local img?

Tags: flutter, dart

i made comment box with flutter with comment_box package but i tried change the 'userImage' to local img but it seems doesn't work. anyone have any solution to change it?
here's my code:

```
Expanded(
          child: CommentBox(
            userImage: 'assets/profile_icon.png',
            child: commentChild(filedata),
            labelText: 'Write a comment...',
            withBorder: false,
            errorText: 'Comment cannot be blank',
            sendButtonMethod: () {
              if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                print(commentController.text);
                setState(() {
                  addComment();
                });

                FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
              } else {
                print("Not validated");
              }
            },
            formKey: formKey,
            commentController: commentController,
            backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
            textColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
            sendWidget: Icon(Icons.send_sharp, size: 30, color: Colors.grey),
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to use your local image for `userImage` parameter. In `comment_box 0.0.17` package configuration, it uses `Network Image` to display `userImage` in **UI**, and it accepts only `URL text (String userImage)`. In this case, you have to configure a custom comment box for your UI or you can continue to search for another package for your UI implementation.

```
dependencies:
  comment_box: ^0.0.17
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the comment_box package to support local image and network image.

Package: [comment_box](https://pub.dev/packages/comment_box)

Example

```dart
import 'package:comment_box/comment/comment.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestMe extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestMeState createState() => _TestMeState();
}

class _TestMeState extends State<TestMe> {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final TextEditingController commentController = TextEditingController();
  List filedata = [
    {
      'name': 'Chuks Okwuenu',
      'pic': 'https://picsum.photos/300/30',
      'message': 'I love to code',
      'date': '2021-01-01 12:00:00'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Biggi Man',
      'pic': 'https://www.adeleyeayodeji.com/img/IMG_20200522_121756_834_2.jpg',
      'message': 'Very cool',
      'date': '2021-01-01 12:00:00'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Tunde Martins',
      'pic': 'assets/img/userpic.jpg',
      'message': 'Very cool',
      'date': '2021-01-01 12:00:00'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Biggi Man',
      'pic': 'https://picsum.photos/300/30',
      'message': 'Very cool',
      'date': '2021-01-01 12:00:00'
    },
  ];

  Widget commentChild(data) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2.0, 8.0, 2.0, 0.0),
            child: ListTile(
              leading: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () async {
                  // Display the image in large form.
                  print("Comment Clicked");
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 50.0,
                  width: 50.0,
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50))),
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 50,
                      backgroundImage: CommentBox.commentImageParser(
                          imageURLorPath: data[i]['pic'])),
                ),
              ),
              title: Text(
                data[i]['name'],
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              subtitle: Text(data[i]['message']),
              trailing: Text(data[i]['date'], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10)),
            ),
          )
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Comment Page"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: CommentBox(
          userImage: CommentBox.commentImageParser(
              imageURLorPath: "assets/img/userpic.jpg"),
          child: commentChild(filedata),
          labelText: 'Write a comment...',
          errorText: 'Comment cannot be blank',
          withBorder: false,
          sendButtonMethod: () {
            if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
              print(commentController.text);
              setState(() {
                var value = {
                  'name': 'New User',
                  'pic':
                      'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GjRHcaendrf6gU5fPIVd8GIl1OgblrMMvGUoCBj4g=s400',
                  'message': commentController.text,
                  'date': '2021-01-01 12:00:00'
                };
                filedata.insert(0, value);
              });
              commentController.clear();
              FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
            } else {
              print("Not validated");
            }
          },
          formKey: formKey,
          commentController: commentController,
          backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          sendWidget: Icon(Icons.send_sharp, size: 30, color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```